# How to get the Bluesoleil A2DP Audio Sink to work?

Tags: windows, usb, audio, bluetooth, a2dp

Using the Bluesoleil stack with my [MSI BToes 2.0](http://www.msi.com/product/net/BToes-2-0--3X-Faster-.html) I was trying to turn my PC running x86 Windows 7 to an A2DP Audio Sink with my Android device *(Samsung Galaxy S II, ICS 4.0.3, Siyah kernel 3.2.6)* as the client device.

The problem is that even though I'm able to establish a connection without any sign of an issue on the part of either the phone or Bluesoleil, there is no sound being sent to the sound card despite my having set the speakers as the output device in the Bluesoleil A2DP settings.

So, have you by chance run into this or a similar problem yourself and found a satisfactory solution? Although there are [posts](http://www.anythingbutipod.com/forum/showpost.php?p=376700&postcount=4) implicative of the fact that I'm not the only one with these problems, there appears to be surprisingly little information concerning the solution.

I'm also open to other suggestions concerning the turning of a PC into a headset for an Android device (a functional USB audio bridge f.ex. would be lovely).

Comment: The following question concerns turning a linux server, rather than a windows desktop, into an A2DP sink: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a SGS2 ATT and use bluesoleil 8. It works out fine. I just checked the A2dp service in bluesoleil and selected the audio output in my android to bluetooth, then it all worked. All the system audio is routed to my pc.

There is not so many chances with options other than bluetooth, since android os doesn't allow audio routing. There are a lot of solutions for playing music files stored in android on pc using wifi or DLNA. But if you are trying to play the system sound of android on pc, bluetooth seems like the only possible way unless you root your phone and hack audiofliner in the os.